# Support new dialect in Spring Data

Tags: spring-data

I want to implement the SQL dialect of the YDB (https://ydb.tech/) in Spring Data. What is the best way to do this? The database has a JDBC driver and R2DBC driver will be ready soon.

I see that the various dialects for popular integration databases are in the core package. Can I introduce a new dialect or should I implement it through spring-data-common by making two different libraries?